# select column which is another table column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

selecting column which is another table column value.what's wrong with this query

```
select 
    geoName 
from 
    hgeo h 
where 
    geoName not in (select (select column_name 
                            from information_schema.columns 
                            where ((column_name = h.levelName) and (table_Name = 'flatgeo'))) 
                    from flatgeo)
```

I think there is some problem

```
(select 
     (select column_name 
      from information_schema.columns 
      where ((column_name = h.levelName) and (table_Name = 'flatgeo')))
```

How to write it?

Comment: Easier to read, easier to answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use meta-information to change the shape of your query. Unless you want to go down the dynamic sql route (which can quickly get complex), I'd go for the following:

```
SELECT
    geoName
FROM hgeo h
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM flatgeo f
      WHERE
      (h.levelName = 'value1' and f.value1 = h.geoName) OR
      (h.levelName = 'value2' and f.value2 = h.geoName)
      //Repeat for each possible levelName value.
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
select GeoName from HGeo where HGeo.GeoName not in 
(select FlatGeo.value1 from FlatGeo union
select FlatGeo.value2 from FlatGeo union
select FlatGeo.value3 from FlatGeo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `tablename` before your column `geoname`. Like `hgeo.geoname`.
do you want to find out the `geoname` of `hgeo` that are not in `flatgeo`?